# Does oracle xe 11g support with apache2, php 7.0 on ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)?

Tags: apache2, oracle, php7

Does oracle xe 11g support with apache2, php 7.0 on ubuntu 16.04?
Please help me, I have already installed oracle xe 11g, apache2 and php 7.0
Surely i must activate oci8 in php 7.0

Please tutorial step by step thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Oracle do not support officially Ubuntu for Oracle Database XE
2. The only mentioned versions of Apache httpd and PHP are 2.2.x and
   5.3 (version XE 11.2 is dated 2011 year)

But you can try and install it. And there is always option to compile php from source (to get OCI support)

For reference: [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/index.htm)

Comment: How about PHP 7 OCI8 2.1.0 is it usable ? 
 [ https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/php-7-oci8-210-available-on-pecl ]

Comment: @Fadlur, seems to be, never try. At the end it come from Oracle engineer.  The only challenge I see is the process of linking this interface to Oracle Client libraries